# How to add libclang to xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I would love to do some syntax coloring and code completion on any given code. Ideas inspired from Apple video http://devimages.apple.com/llvm/videos/Libclang.mov

Can anyone tell me about a sample project which uses libclang to parse objective-c code?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the Étoilé project: http://etoileos.com/news/archive/2010/10/15/1401/

There you'll find SourceCodeKit that integrates clang for syntax highlighting.
(Source: http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/etoile/trunk/Etoile/Languages/SourceCodeKit/ )

Comment: The explanation of how real syntax highlighting differs from that done by Vim is an interesting read.